# NGSI-LD time range query

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I tried doing a query to get entities *(/entities?q=...)* in a specific time range based on a DateTime attribute but I didn't have any luck. I read the NGSI-LD specification on the queries but I couldn't come up with the right solution.

Comment: could you give the whole query you are doing? and which NGSI-LD context broker are you using? also, why you are not using the NGSI-LD temporal API?

Comment: I have just raised an issue on datetime comparison in Orion-LD on [github](https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/issues/938)

Comment: Yes, some more info would be good. Quite impossible to help otherwise